# How to get a reference page for each chapter in apa-like style

Tags: cross-referencing, apa-style

I am trying to get to get the following in apa style.

```
    \begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@BOOK{childs_temperature,
  title = {Practical Temperature Measurement},
  publisher = {Butterworth - Heinemann},
  year = {2001},
  author = {Childs, Peter R N},
  address = {Great Britain},
  edition = {1},
  isbn = {0 7506 5080 X}
  }

  @PHDTHESIS{hashemian,
  author = {Hashemian, Hashem Mehrdad},
  title = {Measurements of dynamic temperatures and pressures in nuclear power plants},
  school = {{The University of Western Ontario}},
  year = {2011},
  type = {PhD {T}hesis}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{natbib}
 \usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{references.bib}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{refsection}
 \chapter{First chapter}
 \section{Foo}
 Some text \cite{childs_temperature}.
 \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
 \end{refsection}

 \begin{refsection}
 \chapter{Second chapter}
 \section{Bar}
 Some text \cite{hashemian}.
 \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
 \end{refsection}

 \nocite{*}
 \printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

I tried changing `\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` to `\usepackage[style=apalike,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`, but I keep on getting errors. How can I get the references in apa-like style? I am new to LaTeX and would appreciate a step-by-step explanation.

Comment: `apalike` is a `.bst` style and `biblatex` does not work with `.bst` files. You will have to find a `biblatex` style you want to use. Similar would be `authoryear` and friends. But if you want full APA compliance, you can use `biblatex-apa`.

Comment: How can I use biblatex-apa? I am fairly new to latex and very confused. Thank you for your help!